# jqgrid header and data row are not align after resize

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I am having a problem that i try to resize some column header, but when i do, the header and the respective data row are not aligned.

Here is the definition of my jqgrid.

Thanks in Advance ;)
Marcelo

```
    var loadGrid = function () {
        uCurriculosGrid.grid.data = $("#gridCurriculos").jqGrid({
            datatype: "local",
            height: "0",
            shrinkToFit: false,
            fixed: true,
            width: 1240,
            emptyrecords: 'Não existem curriculos para serem visualizados com esse filtro.',
            colNames : uCurriculosGrid.grid.myColumnsState.colNames,
            colModel: uCurriculosGrid.grid.myColumnsState.colModel,
            ignoreCase: true,
            multiselect: true,
            multiboxonly: true,
            caption: 'Curriculos',
            pager: '#pager',
            pgbuttons: false,
            pginput: false,
            editurl: "Administracao.aspx",
            viewrecords: true,
            onSelectRow: checkSelected,
            onSelectAll: checkSelected,
            beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) { return false; },
            gridComplete: onGridComplete,
            gridView: false,
            postData: uCurriculosGrid.grid.myColumnsState.filters,
            sortname: uCurriculosGrid.grid.myColumnsState.sortname,
            sortorder: uCurriculosGrid.grid.myColumnsState.sortorder,
            loadComplete: uCurriculosGrid.grid.loadComplete,
            resizeStop: uCurriculosGrid.grid.resizeStop,
            onSortCol: uCurriculosGrid.grid.onSortCol
        }).navGrid('#pager',
        { add: false, edit: true, del: true, search: true, refresh: false, editfunc: editSelected, delfunc: deleteSelected }, //options
        { reloadAfterSubmit: true, viewPagerButtons: false, closeOnEscape: true, closeAfterEdit: true }, // Edit options
        {}, // Add options
        {},
        {}
        );
```

**UPDATE**: I know that the grid's configuration is being saved correcty in the localStorage because when i reload the page, the grid that wasn't aligned becomes aligned.

It gets more weird. When i edit my grid configuration with de columnChooser, and add some column to the Grid, it all works fine. But when i restore to default configurations, this error happens.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the property `shrinkToFit` as `true`;

```
shrinkToFit : true,
```

As given in the [wiki](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions)

> This option, if set, defines how the the width of the columns of the grid should be re-calculated, taking into consideration the width of the grid. If this value is true, and the width of the columns is also set, then every column is scaled in proportion to its width. For example, if we define two columns with widths 80 and 120 pixels, but want the grid to have a width of 300 pixels, then the columns will stretch to fit the entire grid, and the extra width assigned to them will depend on the width of the columns themselves and the extra width available.

Comment: I've already tried to 'play' with the shrinkToFit property. And also with the fixed property.

Answer (score 0):

```
BeforeLoad = function () {
            $('#AdvertisementGrid td:nth-child(6)').attr('colspan',6);
        }
```

It works for me. Here "#AdvertisementGrid" is grid id replace this id to your grid id.